# I can't write on the full width of input on HTML

Tags: html, css, forms, input

I can't write on all the input space. When I create the line (not a box because I removed the left-right-top border) and put padding, I can't write on the full line, only on half of it, and then the previous text will disappear on the left side.

```css
.contato {
  background-color: white;
  width: 75%;
  height: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.contato .header {
  background-color: #353E49;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: lightgrey;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-width: 0.5px;
}

.contato h1 {
  margin-left: 10%;
  color: white;
  padding: 5% 0 5% 0;
  font-family: "lato regular";
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size:
}

input,
textarea {
  display: block;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CECFD3;
  padding: 1.5% 50% 2% 0;
  resize: vertical;
  width: auto;
  font-family: "Lato Regular";
  color: darkgray;
  font-size: 1.05 rem;
}

.preencher {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: lightgrey;
  border-width: 0.5px;
  border-top: none;
  padding-top: 5%;
  margin-top: -5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="contato">
  <form name="contato" method="POST" netlify>
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Contato</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="preencher">
      <p>
        <label>Nome: <input type="text" name="nome"></label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>E-mail: <input type="email" name="email"></label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>Empresa/site: <input cols="60" type="email" name="empresa"></label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>Mensagem: <textarea name="mensagem"></textarea></label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
      </p>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

You can see the result on jsfiddle and understand better what I said: https://jsfiddle.net/cLsgL3d1/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input `padding` is set to 50% and your width is set to auto, which is causing your `width` to be 50% and `margin` to be fill the rest of the space. Change your left/right padding to zero (or whatever), and set your width to 100% rather than auto.

```css
.contato {
    background-color:white;
    width:75%;
    height:80%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:10%;
}

.contato .header {
    background-color: #353E49;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:lightgrey;
    border-bottom:none;
    border-width: 0.5px;
}

.contato h1 {
    margin-left:10%;
    color:white;
    padding:5% 0 5% 0;
    font-family:"lato regular";
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-size:    
}

input,textarea {
    display:block;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CECFD3;
    padding: 1.5% 0 2% 0;
    resize:vertical;
    width:100%;
    font-family:"Lato Regular";
    color:darkgray;
    font-size:1.05 rem;
}

.preencher {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color:lightgrey;
    border-width: 0.5px;
    border-top:none;
    padding-top:5%;
    margin-top:-5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="contato">
    <form name="contato" method="POST" netlify>
     
        <div class="header">
           <h1>Contato</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="preencher">
            <p>
                <label>Nome: <input type="text" name="nome"></label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>E-mail: <input type="email" name="email"></label>
                </p>
                <p>
                   <label>Empresa/site: <input cols="60" type="email" name="empresa"></label>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Mensagem: <textarea name="mensagem"></textarea></label>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <button type="submit">Send</button>
                </p>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh my god, it was so simple! Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help! Feel free to mark my answer as correct :D

Answer (score 1):

You need to add/replace this CSS to your existing code:

`input { width: 100%; padding: 1.5% 5% 2% 0; box-sizing: border-box; }`

Your 50% right padding is what is causing the input to allow such a small amount of text. If you are wanting the input to stop before the right edge of the container, I'd suggest adding padding-right to the parent

tags.

Answer (score 0):

I just modified this code and it works fine now:

```
input,textarea {
        display:block;
        background: transparent;
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #CECFD3;
        padding: 1.5% 0 2% 0; // you have added 50% of right padding. which is the reason of the problem. 
        resize:vertical;
        width:100%;
        font-family:"Lato Regular";
        color:darkgray;
        font-size:1.05 rem;
    }
```